# What is the best way to handle state/props if i want to fetch and display a separate component when a specific link is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I created a CodeSandbox so I can elaborate my question.
I would like to ask for your suggestion on my Project:

I currently have a website portfolio app that are divided into 4 pages:

1. Loading.js directly fetch -> Home.js
2. About.js
3. Contact.js
4. Work.js – it displays a  link of my projects that will open a Sliding Sidebar/Side Drawer

feature.

What I wanted to do is to fetch the individual project components and pass it in the Sliding Sidebar once a specific project was clicked by the user.

My question is what is the best way to manage the state?  how do I pass the props from the project that was clicked and display the specific project component from the components folder?

[CodeSandbox Link  <----](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-oskar-cuysk)

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start do you mean something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated work.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import StyledWorkNav from "./StyledWorkNav";
import SideDrawer, { StyledDrawer } from "./SideDrawer";
import Project1 from "./components/Project1";
import Project2 from "./components/Project2";
import Project3 from "./components/Project3";

const Work = () => {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([
        { name: 'Project 1', projId: '1', dataText: 'Proj 1', comp:"" },
    { name: 'Project 2', projId: '2', dataText: 'Proj 2', comp:"Project2" },
    { name: 'Project 3', projId: '3', dataText: 'Proj 3', comp:"Project3" },
    ]);
    const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState(null);

  const strToComponent = {
    Project1: <Project1/>,
    Project2: <Project2/>,
    Project3: <Project3/>
  }






  const openDrawerHandler = () => {
    if (!drawerOpen) {
      setDrawerOpen(true);
    } else {
      setDrawerOpen(false);
    }
  };

  const closeDrawerHandler = () => {
    setDrawerOpen(false);
  };

  // -------------------****** update **************

  let drawer;
  if (drawerOpen) {
    drawer = (
      <SideDrawer 
         close={closeDrawerHandler} 
         sidebar={{ StyledDrawer }} 

         // pass down here one of the wanted component : project1.js, 2 etc..
         project={
            <Project1
                selectedProject={selectedProject} // you can pass the selected 
                                                  // project as prop for 
                                                  // project1.js for example 
            />
         }
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <StyledWorkNav>
                <ul>
                {projects.map((project) => (
                    <li
                        key={project.projId}
                        onClick={() => {
                            setSelectedProject(project);
                            openDrawerHandler();
                        }}>
                        <p data-text={project.dataText}>{project.name}</p>
                    </li>
                ))}
                {selectedProject && drawer}
            </ul>
    </StyledWorkNav>
  );
};

export default Work;
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, Nassim! It Worked! what I've missed on this one is that i didnt know that i could pass the component as props - ex:  project={
            <Project1
                selectedProject={selectedProject} // you can pass the selected 
                                                  // project as prop for 
                                                  // project1.js for example 
            />
         }

Comment: I think i mightve spoken too soon, so whats happening was when i click on a different Project (Project2 for example), The Project 1 still displays

Comment: This is how I thought it would worked out:                                                                                let drawer;
 if (drawerOpen) {
  drawer = (
   <SideDrawer
    close={closeDrawerHandler}
    drawerClass={{ StyledDrawer }}
    project={
     ((<Proj1 selectedProject={selectedProject} />),
     (<Proj2 selectedProject={selectedProject} />),
     (<Proj3 selectedProject={selectedProject} />),
     (<Proj4 selectedProject={selectedProject} />))
    }
   />
  );
 }

Comment: strToComponent and setProjects are assigned but never been used. i tried converting projects into an array. not really sure what the strToComponent is used for. Not sure where or how to use it, but i assume it should convert the string in comp value into a Component, but again not sure where to call strToComponent.

Answer (score 0):

**you can do something like this :**
**Upadate**

```
imports ......

// this state will contain all your projects 
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([
       {
         id: 1,
         name: "project1"
       }, 
       {
         id: 2,
         name: "project2"
       },
       .....
])

// this will contain on of the project selected from the list of 
// projects
const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState({
      id: 1,
      name: "project1"
})

return (
<>
  <List>
     { projects.map(project => (
         <ListItem key={project.id} onClick={() => setSelectedProject(project)}>
            {project.name}
         </ListItem>
       ))
     }
  </List>

     {
       selectedProject && 
          <Sidebar // the selected project goes here and change every time a different project selected
            project={selectedProject}
          />
     }
</>
)

export ......
```

Comment: what should I put inside the array?           
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([{}, {}, ...])                     Is it possible to put in the individual project components inside the useState() array?

Comment: yes of course , you can split it as you want , that's even better. i just wanted to show you a global adea. see my update

Comment: I went with your approach, and I was able to get rid of the long list <ul> and <li>

Comment: the only thing thats left is to pass the specific Project Component into the side drawer.

Comment: how would the specific Project Component look like in your updated code? for example on Proj1.js?

Comment: see the answer below.
**Note** : if the projects you want to display have same UI (same data structure), there's no need to create many project component (in the component foler) as many as the mount of projects you have in the database.